# Boolean CommandParameter in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, routed-commands

I have this code (which works just right):

```
<KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding ReturnResultCommand}">
    <KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
        <s:Boolean>
            True
        </s:Boolean>
    </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
</KeyBinding>
```

Where "s" is of course the System namespace.

But this command is called quite a few times and it really inflates otherwise rather simple XAML code. Is this really the shortest notation of boolean command parameter in XAML (other than splitting the command into several commands)?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This might be a bit of a hack but you can derive from the `KeyBinding` class:

```cs
public class BoolKeyBinding : KeyBinding
{
    public bool Parameter
    {
        get { return (bool)CommandParameter; }
        set { CommandParameter = value; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<local:BoolKeyBinding ... Parameter="True"/>
```

**And another not so weird solution:**

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->
    <s:Boolean x:Key="True">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="False">False</s:Boolean>
</Application.Resources>
```

Usage:

```
<KeyBinding ... CommandParameter="{StaticResource True}"/>
```

Comment: It is not only for KeyBindings, but for Buttons and such as well.

Comment: Then what about my second method which i just added?

Comment: Interesting idea, that didn't occur to me. I will try it.

Comment: @H.B. Why does mine always return false? I can't get this to work.

Comment: @Igor: I don't know, try to construct an minimal working example and post a new question if you were not able to solve the problem in the process. Unless people know what you do it's hard to fix.

Comment: @H.B. Nice answer, maybe you could add this: `xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` to your answer :)

Answer (score 75):

The easiest is to define the following in the Resources

```
<System:Boolean x:Key="FalseValue">False</System:Boolean>
<System:Boolean x:Key="TrueValue">True</System:Boolean>
```

and use it like:

```
<Button CommandParameter="{StaticResource FalseValue}"/>
```

Comment: and you need to add: `xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` to the user control

Answer (score 36):

Or, maybe that:

```
<Button.CommandParameter>
    <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
</Button.CommandParameter>
```

Where s is the namespace:

```
 xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Answer (score 29):

I just found an even more generic solution with this markup extension:

```cs
public class SystemTypeExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private object parameter;

    public int Int{set { parameter = value; }}
    public double Double { set { parameter = value; } }
    public float Float { set { parameter = value; } }
    public bool Bool { set { parameter = value; } }
    // add more as needed here

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

Usage ("wpf:" is the namespace where the extension lives in):

```
<KeyBinding Key="F8" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{wpf:SystemType Bool=True}"/>
```

You even get the options `True` and `False` after typing `Bool=` and type safety!

Comment: @marbel82 as  far as I know you can omit the "Extension" in the same way as "Attribute" for attributes. Try for yourself! But adding extension won't hurt of course.

Comment: Onur you're right! I didn't know that. You should write this info in the answer. Previously I tested your code, but I had a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: That is so slick it is sick.  Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Just create a markupextension per type (e.g. `BooleanExtension`) and you can write e.g. `CommandParameter={x:Boolean True}` similar to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/built-in-types-for-common-xaml-language-primitives

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps something like

```
<KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding ReturnResultCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{x:Static StaticBoolean.True}" />
```

where `StaticBoolean` is

```cs
public static class StaticBoolean
{
    public static bool True
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. The value is passed into the command as string (which is also not what I want).

Comment: Hmm, how would I use the converter in this context?

Comment: Sorry found something simpler.

Comment: That was an interesting evolution i must say, saw all the steps :P Now it's down to a bool resource (which you could do in Xaml as well, like in my answer)

Comment: I really like your solution. I suggest a small improvement. Instead of `get` simply initialize a constant `public static bool True = true;` and add another constant `public static bool False = false;`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach where you define your own markup extensions that return `True` or `False` (or any other value you wish). Then you simply use them right in XAML like any other markup extension:

```
public class TrueExtension : MarkupExtension {
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => true;
}

public class FalseExtension : MarkupExtension {
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => false;
}

public class DoubleExtension : MarkupExtension {
    public DoubleExtension(){};
    public DoubleExtension(double value) => Value = value;
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => Value;
}
```

You then use them like this (assuming your imported namespace is `mx`):

```
<KeyBinding Key="Enter"
    Command="{Binding ReturnResultCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{mx:True}" />

<Button Visibility="{Binding SomeProperty,
    Converter={SomeBoolConverter},
    ConverterParameter={mx:True}}">

<!-- This guarantees the value passed is a double equal to 42.5 -->
<Button Visibility="{Binding SomeProperty,
    Converter={SomeDoubleConverter},
    ConverterParameter={mx:Double 42.5}}">
```

I actually define lots of custom `MarkupExtension` classes for a lot of common things that I don't want to necessarily store in my resources.