# How do I pass decimal value as CommandParameter for a command using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, prism

I have an app written using c# and WPF on the top of Prism 6 framework.

I am trying to create a button using XAMl, when clicked, I want to be pass a fixed decimal value to my view-model.

```
<Button Content="5"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{Binding ProcessAmount}"
        CommandParameter="5.00000"
        FontSize="24"
        Height="75"
        Width="85" />
```

In my view-model I have the following

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public DelegateCommand<decimal?> ProcessAmount { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ProcessAmount = new DelegateCommand<decimal?>(HandleProcessAmount, CanProcessAmount);
    }

    private bool CanProcessAmount(decimal? amount)
    {
        return amount.HasValue && amount.Value != 0;
    }

    private void HandleProcessAmount(decimal? amount)
    {
        // do something with the amount
    }
}
```

But when I compile the app, I get an error in the XAML view `Specified cast is not valid.`

How can I send a fixed decimal value from the view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xaml world, every number is treated as `Double`. You would need to cast/ convert manually, otherwise unexpected may occurs. This means, in your view model, retrieve the number as `double?` instead of `decimal?`, then cast/ convert it to `decimal` as appropriately. For ex:

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public DelegateCommand<double?> ProcessAmount { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ProcessAmount = new DelegateCommand<double?>(HandleProcessAmount, CanProcessAmount);
    }

    private bool CanProcessAmount(double? amount)
    {
        return amount.HasValue && amount.Value != 0;
    }

    private void HandleProcessAmount(double? amount)
    {
        decimal amountInDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(amount.Value); // convert it to decimal

        // do something with the amount
    }
}
```

The good thing about this is that it is easier to perform calculation on `double` type number than `decimal` type number. But, I guess this is not what you wanted.

The **solution** to your question is specify the type explicitly to be `Decimal` in the xaml. You need to import the `System mscorlib` and then assign that `System`'s `Decimal` to the `CommandParameter`.

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<Button Content="5"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{Binding ProcessAmount}"
        FontSize="24"
        Height="75"
        Width="85">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <s:Decimal>5.00000</s:Decimal>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

This eliminates the necessary to convert number type on the VM side.

Comment: For some funny reason this doesn't work in UWP.

Comment: Got it, it would be `x:Int32`, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-intrinsic-data-types).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of literally assigning `5.00000` to `CommandParameter`, try defining the value in XAML, as a resource (as per [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13313286/510627)). Your XAML code could look something like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <system:Double x:Key="MyDouble">5.0000</system:Double>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="5"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Command="{Binding ProcessAmount}"
                CommandParameter="{StaticResource MyDouble}"
                FontSize="24"
                Height="75"
                Width="85" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is, that you assign `string` "5" to the `CommandParameter`. There are several solutions. One of them to set `Decimal` in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="....." 
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"  
/>
<Button Content="5"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Command="{Binding ProcessAmount}"
    FontSize="24"
    Height="75"
    Width="85">
    <Button.CommandParameter><sys:Decimal>5.00000</sys:Decimal></Button.CommandParameter>
    <!-- <Button.CommandParameter><x:Null/></Button.CommandParameter> If you want to set value to null-->
</Button>
```

or handle `ComandParameter` as a `string`:

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public DelegateCommand<string> ProcessAmount { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ProcessAmount = new DelegateCommand<string>(HandleProcessAmount, CanProcessAmount);
    }

    private bool CanProcessAmount(string amountStr)
    {
        try
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(amountStr) != 0;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void HandleProcessAmount(string amount)
    {
        // do something with the amount
    }
}
```