# WPF command /w boolean parameter leaves button disabeld

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, disabled-input

I'm having an issue with binding a Command to a button, with a Boolean CommandParameter.
The result is always a disabled/not clickable button.

In WPF with the relayCommand from  Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.mvvm.input.RelayCommand

the code:
XAML:

```
...
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
<s:Boolean x:Key="TrueValue">True</s:Boolean>
...

<Button       
    Content="Bool cmd"
    Command="{Binding BoolCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{StaticResource TrueValue}">
    <!--CommandParameter="{Binding SomeBoolProperty}">-->
    <!--<Button.CommandParameter>
        <s:Boolean>
            False
        </s:Boolean>
    </Button.CommandParameter>-->
</Button>

<Button       
    Content="String cmd"
    Command="{Binding StringCommand}"
    CommandParameter="Test"/>
```

Behind:

```
    private bool _someBoolProperty;
    public bool SomeBoolProperty
    {
        get => _someBoolProperty;
        set => SetProperty(ref _someBoolProperty, value);
    }

    private ICommand _boolCommand;
    public ICommand BoolCommand { get => _boolCommand ?? (_boolCommand = new RelayCommand<bool>(SetBool, (bool x) => canExecute)); }

    private void SetBool(bool state)
    {
        //...
    }

    private bool canExecute {
        get => true;
    }

    private ICommand _stringCommand;
    public ICommand StringCommand { get => _stringCommand ?? (_stringCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(SetString)); }

    private void SetString(string state)
    {
        //...
    }
```

Some extra info:

- the xaml is inside a UserControl inside a DataTemplate.
- breakpoint in the SetString function is hit, and has no issues.
- canExecute is **not** hit.
- 'Xaml Binding failures ' window shows no issues with this.

i did read and try (see the commended code) some variations of this answer:
[Boolean CommandParameter in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997446/boolean-commandparameter-in-xaml)

But the button is always grayed out; disabled; not clickable.
Any ideas on what causes this button to be disabled?

[image: Result]

Comment: The second parameter for the relaycommand should be a Func that returns a boolean. maybe: _boolCommand = new RelayCommand<bool>(SetBool, (bool x) => return canExecute)); might fix it?

Comment: @GertHermans I turned the CanExecute into a function. i cant find a syntax that allows a return at that position.
also: RelayCommand takes a Func<bool> while
RelayCommand<object> takes a predicate<bool> as second parameter. (i dont really  know the difference tho)

Comment: A Func allows more flexibility in terms of parameter count and types and the returned type. A Predicate always returns a bool. A Predicate<int> describes a delegate that takes a parameter of type int and returns a bool. This is equal to a Func<int, bool>.

Comment: There is no issue with your posted code. I mean you could simplify it e.g., `x => true` as CanExecute delegate. Also pay attention to a consistent naming scheme. The property should be named `CanExecute` with capital `C`. You should post a complete but minimal working example that we can review. The RelayCommand implementation could also be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is confiusing to me, your intial claim is you have problems with the button that has `... Boolean CommandParameter ..`, than you show as a button with the command `Command="{Binding BoolCommand}"` which tries to use a `boolean` as `CommandParamter` but than you start talking about a different command `breakpoint in the SetString function is hit, and has no issues.`, so where is your issue?

Comment: I have added a link to the RelayCommand docs. (from Microsoft.Toolkit.MVVM.Input)
the reason for added the string in the example is to show similar code does work, and to prevent adding all of the source code. and to prevent questions like, do you have the correct datacontext.

Comment: I have just tried this in a new clean project, and it runs fine. (bool cmd button is enabeld)
But my question remains. perhaps its better worded as 'Why is this `BoolCommand` not binding correctly'?  maybe it is because its inside a datatemplate? 
Any feedback on how to describe this problem question better is welcome. or now i dont know what to edit or show that can help

Comment: Change `Content="Bool cmd"` to `Content="{Binding}"` what does the Button have as a content? If it isn't the type where your command is declared than your datacontext is wrong and you have to specify it. eg change the binding of the command to `Command="{Binding BoolCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}"` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource

Comment: Please anser to comments with @[UserName] so that the user gets notified.

Comment: @Lelen: Your issue is not reproducible based on the information you have provided.

Comment: @Lelen i have the same issue, have you found a solution for it?